# How Can I ignore more than one directory in .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

When I put "git status" I get this:

```
    main/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    posting/__pycache__/views.cpython-36.pyc
```

I tried putting this in my .gitignore file:

```
main/__pycache__/
posting/__pycache__/
```

But, did not work

Comment: Simply putting `__pycache__/` should ignore all of them. If you already have pushed those directories onto your repository, you might want to delete them first.

Comment: If the files are tracked already, adding them to `.gitignore` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `__pycache__/` to your .gitignore. It iwll then ignore all `__pycache__` directories within your project.

Comment: thanks everybody.

I deleted the pycache directory and then I put in .gitignore __pycache__/ 
and It works